# Correct usage of Nexus IQ for Javascript based projects

Tags: jenkins, nexus

I have just started out trying to use Nexus IQ server to scan a Javascript based project of mine which uses libraries from npm and bower.

I am using the Jenkins Nexus Platfom Plugin and have configured a build step to connect to our Nexus IQ server instance. As part of the plugin I have configured it to scan for Javascript files within locations of the built project where the npm and bower dependencies are installed to.

The final report that gets generated on our Nexus IQ server is huge, in fact it reaches a limit of results (10000 rows) it can display and so is unable to display everything it finds.

I'm not 100% sure if I am doing things right here, and wondered whether anyone else out there has any experience of how to get sensible results from Nexus when scanning npm\bower installed dependencies.

I'm looking at the Licence Analysis section now and can see over 3000 rows of various 'Not supported' licence threats coming from libraries that havent directly been included in the project, e.g. listed in my projects package.json file, but I guess these are child dependencies of libraries I have specified to be installed.

Can anyone offer any advice on the best approach to getting Nexus IQ to handle Javascript projects that rely on npm\bower dependencies?

Comment: i haven't use nexus IQ specifically, but with static analysis in general, maybe you want to either 1) fix a bunch of the issues locally before adding to jenkins or 2) configure it (hopefully this is possible) to ignore a bunch of the issues that you don't care about.

Comment: Nexus IQ is not static analysis. I'll see if I can get someone from our IQ team to take a gander here and offer you some tips, PS.

Comment: The license threats could be completely valid, transitive dependencies are potentially licensed differently compared to what you imported, or not licensed at all (which you've pointed out). That can be bad, depending: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148146/open-source-code-with-no-license-can-i-fork-it

Answer (score 0):

All that the NexusIQ needs to analyse a project, is:

- `package-lock.json` to identify all dependencies, including transitive ones
- optionally: `package.json` to build a dependecy tree (not available otherwise)

That's what's enough to provide when performing a manual action `Evaluate a file` on an application.

For the jenkins plugin step, configure it e.g. as follows:

```js
    nexusPolicyEvaluation(
        iqApplication: 'SampApp',
        iqStage: 'build',
        iqScanPatterns: [
            [ scanPattern: '**/package-lock.json' ],
            [ scanPattern: '**/package.json' ]
        ])
```

See: [Steps to analyze using the Jenkins plugin](https://help.sonatype.com/iqserver/analysis/npm-application-analysis#npmApplicationAnalysis-StepstoanalyzeusingtheJenkinsplugin)